# Working With UITabBarControllers, what's the best way to pass data when unable to use segue?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.5

I need to return a specific instance variable(an object) of theFirstViewController(first tab) to theSecondViewController(second tab) so I am not using a segue.

What is considered best practice for passing data between tabs? I have searched extensively and have not found a clear answer. I have tried what I think is nearly every option except using a singleton. Would it be acceptable to use a singleton for this purpose?  I will need to be archiving the data anyways.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to declare your ViewControllers as instance variables of your app delegate

add a property to your view controller classes say(A and B) .

Say you wanted to Pass objects between your view controllers you can add a property to each:

```
@interface AViewController : UIViewController {
    BViewController *b;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) BViewController *b;;

@end

@interface BViewController : UIViewController {
    AViewController *a;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AViewController *a;

@end
```

When you initialise your view controller you can then set this property to the object context initialised previously.

You have mentioned a tab bar controller. If your view controllers are wired through IB all you have to do is to set these parameters in your application delegate applicationDidFinishLaunching: method, before the tab bar controller is displayed:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{

    AViewController *aViewController;
    BViewController *bViewController;
    ...
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet AViewController *aViewController;
@property (retain) IBOutlet BViewController *aViewController;

@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate

...

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
...

    aViewController.b = bViewController;

    bViewController.a = aViewController;

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

to create objects Of viewControllers you can use

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

ViewController* viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
```